# Sufficient statistic equivalence

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $\theta'$, $\theta \in \Theta$ such that $\theta' \neq \theta$. I want to prove that $T$ is a sufficient statistic if and only if $$\frac{f(x,\theta')}{f(x,\theta)}$$
is a function dependent only on $T(x)$.

I tried to use factorization theorem but for different parameters functions can be different and it leads nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [factorisation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher%E2%80%93Neyman_factorization_theorem) we know that $T$ is sufficient if and only if:

$$f_\theta(x) = h(x) g_\theta(T(x)).$$

So we then have:

$$R_{\theta', \theta}(x) \equiv \frac{f_\theta'(x)}{f_\theta(x)} = \frac{h(x) g_\theta'(T(x))}{h(x) g_\theta(T(x))} = \frac{g_\theta'(T(x))}{g_\theta(T(x))},$$

which depends on $x$ only through $T(x)$.